# Converting a string into a class

Tags: c++, string, class, oop

I want to make an application in C++ that can solve the rubik's cube. My cube class looks like this:

```
class cube
{
    face fete[7];
    mutare mutari[1001];
public:
    cube();
    void Print();
    void setMoves(string x);
};
```

My class "mutare" is an abstract parent class that represents the move it needs to apply to solve the cube. For example mutari[0] = L; mutari[1] = R; where L and R are childs of "mutare".

In setMoves() i have to go through "x" and when i find L , i will do something like

```
if(x[i] == 'L')
{
    mutare[last]=new L();
    last++;
}
```

is there a way to do this without doing an if for every single child class i have?
I do have 12 child classes and I really don't want to do 12 if statements.

Comment: What language is this please? If you could add the tag that helps. I guess c++ yes?

Comment: Yes , sorry , i shall update my post

Comment: I think the amount of help you need to solve this issue is beyond this site, you are getting in to bigger software design and structuring questions which require extended discussion.

Comment: to avoid using an `if`, you can use a `switch` statement or use something like a  `map<char,std::function<mutare()>>`